# List all elements of the cyclic group $\langle f\rangle$ generated by $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups

Let $f = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 &7 & 8 & 9 \\
7 & 9 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$ and $g = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 &7 & 8 & 9 \\
9 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 3 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$.

How do I find elements of the cyclic group $\langle f\rangle$ generated by $f$? Similarly, how do I find elements of the cyclic group $\langle g\rangle$ generated by $g$?

First I wrote $f$ and $g$ as a product of disjoint cycles: $f=(17)(29)(35)(48)$ and $g=(1964)(2835)$. Then I can see that their orders are $2$ and $4$ respectively. Now I am stuck. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: The list of elements in a group of order $2$ is only two elements long and you found one of them. Listing elements of $\langle g \rangle$ will arguably need a bit more computation.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: @PatrickStevens I thought the \langle \rangle fairy was only a myth. Thank you. \newcommand{\<}{\langle} and \newcommand{\>}{\rangle} are the first two non-otherwise-mandatory lines in my LaTeX template.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the composition of two permutations? If so, you can just calculate $g \cdot g$ and $g \cdot g \cdot g$ to get the two remaining elements of $\langle g \rangle$

Comment: $f^2= id$, So the the group it generates is $\{id, f\}$.

Comment: You have to compute „powers“ of $g$. Disjoint cycles are commuting.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I then find an element $h$ such that $fh=1$?

Comment: This does raise the subsidiary question of whether "finding" or "listing" the elements of $\langle g \rangle$ means simply specifying them in any non-redundant or tautological way (e.g. as a list of powers of $g$ which is determined once the order of $g$ is known), or listing them in some more specific way (e.g. in terms of products of disjoint cycles or perhaps writing them in the original notation used to represent $f$ and $g$).

Comment: Daniyar: $h= f$ because if $fh - id$, and a group element's inverse is unique, and we already know that $ff =  f^2$ = id., then it must be the case that $h=f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $f$ is a product of disjoint transpositions the cyclic group generated by $f$ is equal to the set containing the identity and $f$ itself.

The cyclic group generated by $g$ is the group $\{Id, g, g^2, g^3\}$ as $g$ is the product of two disjoint $4$-cycles.

Comment: Already answered in comments.

Comment: @amWhy Was not looking at comments when typing the answer...

Comment: That's not my point.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I then find an element $h$ such that $fh=1$?

Comment: One only needs to see the original f to know that f^2 is the identity.

Comment: Regarding [answering in comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32217/answer-to-a-short-question-that-was-already-answered-in-comments), this looks like a proper answer to me, so the fact of it being answered in the comments is not relevant.